# How can I make Terraform replace a null value with a default value?

Tags: terraform

The Terraform documentation indicates this should already be happening:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html

> null: a value that represents absence or omission. If you set an argument of a resource or module to null, Terraform behaves as though you had completely omitted it — it will use the argument's default value if it has one, or raise an error if the argument is mandatory.

I'm calling a module "foo" that has the following variable file:

```
variable "bar" {
  type    = string
  default = "HelloWorld"
}
```

*Example 1*

When I call it using this code:

```
module "foo" {
  source = "../modules/foo"
  bar = null
}
```

The result is an error.  Invalid value for "str" parameter: argument must not be null.  Trigger when bar is being used.

*Example 2*

When I call it using this code (omitting it, rather than nulling it):

```
module "foo" {
  source = "../modules/foo"
  # bar = null
}
```

The result is that it works.  The "bar" variable is defaulted to "HelloWorld".

This appears to be a bug In Terraform that someone else also raised but wasn't resolved.
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/27730

**Does anyone know a solution or a work around?**

Version information:

```
Terraform v1.0.5
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v3.51.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v3.1.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.1.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/time v0.7.2
```

**Workaround**

Based on @Matt Schuchard's comment and some research there's a ugly solution using the conditional check:

```
variable "foo" {
  type    = string
  default = "HelloWorld"
}
locals {
  foo = var.foo == null ? "HelloWorld" : var.foo
}
```

**Why**

My use case is an attempt to avoid duplicated code.  I have 2 very similar modules, one being a subset of the other.  The solution I'm using is to put the modules in sequence calling each, i.e. a grandparent, parent and child.

I want to have the variables available to the "grandparent" but if they're omitted then the module below "child" should set them using a default value, e.g. "HelloWorld".  But to exposed those variables all the way through the family line I have to include them in all modules and in the high modules (grandparent and parent) I want to default them to null, allowing them to be optional but also still causing them to be set to a default in the "child" further down the line.

...I think I need a diagram.

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24142 that's linked to in your original link? Basically the bug is in the documentation and that it shouldn't currently say `or module`. If you don't want to change the module's default variable and instead use that then don't specify the module parameter. If there's a use case where you would need to do that and only conditionally set it to anything other than the default then it might be worth showing your use case, ideally as a [mcve].

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Is there a design pattern equivalent for module declarations as exists for provider resource/data optional arguments i.e. `<conditional> ? <default_override> : null` ternary though? Is it safe to assume the root cause for `null` not being an acceptable type for module arguments is due to `object` optional arguments and the `default` function in module variable declarations both being tied to an experimental language feature still as of 1.0.x?

Comment: Not as far as I know. `null` would be the obvious way to make it work but it doesn't currently work in Terraform so you can't use it. I've not had a use case for conditionally setting module parameters (it smells slightly of you configuring something to do something quite different in a for_each/count loop in which case it probably wants separating out for blast radius anyway) but if I did have that use case and controlled the module source then I'd fall back to the old pre-`null` days and use empty strings and conditionally check on that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the link @ydaetskcor I missed that one.  It looks like this issue is still open, they'd like to fix it but it's now become an expected behaviour and they're worried it will break existing code.  I also tried to explain the requirement.  The use case is to avoid duplicated code so perhaps there's an easier solution.

Comment: This PR will fix this issue https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/29832 release for terraform 1.1.0

Comment: Please do not add answers (or solutions) into questions. Please add [an actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: That said this all seems to basically boil down to, this is a known bug so of limited use moving forward

Answer (score 25):

As of Terraform 1.1.0, `variable` declarations now support a [`nullable` argument](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#disallowing-null-input-values). It defaults to `true` to preserve the existing behavior. However, any variable with `nullable=false` that is unspecified *or set to `null`* will instead be assigned the default value.

##### **`main.tf`**:

```
variable "nullable" {
  type    = string
  default = "Used default value"
}

output "nullable" {
  value = coalesce(var.nullable, "[null]")
}

variable "non_nullable" {
  type     = string
  default  = "Used default value"
  nullable = false
}

output "non_nullable" {
  value = coalesce(var.non_nullable, "[null]")
}
```

##### **`terraform.tfvars`**

```
nullable     = null
non_nullable = null
```

Note the use of `coalesce` in the *output* blocks. Terraform elides any outputs that are set to `null`, so this ensures that any `null` value still shows something in the output.

After applying this configuration, we can see from running `terraform output` that when `nullable=true` (the default) a variable keeps an explicitly set `null` value but with `nullable=false` any `null` value is ignored in favor of the `default`.

```
# terraform output
non_nullable = "Used default value"
nullable = "[null]"
```

Answer (score 10):

### This is for older versions of Terraform

Use the `nullable` approach if using Terraform 1.1.x or above and if you do not need to support older versions of terraform

---

You can set the default to `null` and set the real default value in the `local` via a [`coalesce`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/coalesce.html) function

### Use try

- This works for a null and empty string

```terraform
variable "foo" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

locals {
  # return var.foo if it's not null
  # return "HelloWorld" if var.foo is null
  foo = try(length(var.foo), 0) > 0 ? var.foo : "HelloWorld"
}

output "foo" {
  value = local.foo
}
```

---

### Use coalesce

- This only works for a null string and not an empty string

```terraform
variable "foo" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

locals {
  # return var.foo if it's not null
  # return "HelloWorld" if var.foo is null
  foo = coalesce(var.foo_coalesce, "HelloWorld")
}

output "foo" {
  value = local.foo
}
```

---

Using the default value of `null` returns `HelloWorld`

```terraform
$ terraform apply -auto-approve

...

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

foo = "HelloWorld"
```

Using a new value negates the default set in the `local`

```terraform
$ terraform apply -auto-approve -var="foo=HelloUniverse"

...

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

foo = "HelloUniverse"
```

Comment: `coalesce()` is not a perfect solution, as it will also [discard empty string arguments](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/coalesce).

Comment: @GregHensley you can set a validation on the input var to allow either null or a non empty string

Comment: @GregHensley I updated the example to include `coalesce()` and a `try(length())` style. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I hope a combination of `contains()` with a condition can solve the problem (terraform versions > 1.xx)

I could solve a for_each solution based on this combination.
In the following example, the .value part contains a set of attributes.
A bit lazy to experiment with the exact problem ;) , but this may help.

```
your_target_attr = contains(keys(each.value), "your_possible_attribute_value") ? each.value.your_possible_attribute_value : var.your_default_value
```